# The prefixIcon of TextField widget in flutter disappears on focusing TextField. How to solve?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Was just exploring flutter and got stuck. The prefixIcon disappears on clicking field and it appears back when focused out. How to solve this ? The code is as below. Tried removing the key of form. I want the icon to stay even if focused in or focused out. Is there any other property to set? 
Couldn't be able to find a fix.

```
        class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
          String _email = "";
          String _password = "";

          final  _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
          final FocusNode _emailFocus = FocusNode();
          final FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode();



          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(widget.title),
              ),
              body: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0,vertical: 100.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child:Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextFormField(
                              focusNode: _emailFocus,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Username or email',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person), //prefixIcon
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                  hintText: "example@mail.com",
                                )
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                            ),
                              TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              focusNode: _passwordFocus,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Password',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                  )
                            ) ,
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Validate will return true if the form is valid, or false if
                                  // the form is invalid.
                                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    // Process data.
                                  }
                                },
                                child: Text('Submit'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
              )
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: Hello raj, i copied your code and tried it and the prefix icons stay when focused. however your problem is that your form widget is not wrapped in a scrollable widget, therefore the keyboard might cause some overflow issues.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the icon disappearing issue. What exactly are you facing, can you add a screenshot or gif?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was that I had set the primary colour to white. So whenever the field was focused it was disappering as the background was also white. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

the issue came to me when i add TextField to AppBar as title.
to fix this, just add color to icon.

e.g.

```
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person), //prefixIcon
```

should be replaced with

```
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.black,), //prefixIcon
```

i post an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37690), but no response yet.

Comment: My issue was I did override the primary color to white.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _email = "";
  String _password = "";

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final FocusNode _emailFocus = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('hi'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 50, right: 50),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                      focusNode: _emailFocus,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Username or email',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person), //prefixIcon
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: "example@mail.com",
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      focusNode: _passwordFocus,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Validate will return true if the form is valid, or false if
                        // the form is invalid.
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          // Process data.
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Submit'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.

You've probably set `primaryColor` and `backgroundColor` to the same colors. Try setting another color for the `prefixIcon` using the color property of the icon.

This helped me fix my issue with icons disappearing on focusing the TextField.

I hope this will solve your issue as well.